# Regular expression to match third charecter

Tags: c#

I am trying to identify third character is 5 or not in my string.  Can you help me in writing regular expression for this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just check the third character `myString[2] == '5'` or something like that rather than all the machinery of a regex?

Comment: I don't have option to write code here. It should be through regular expression only..  Thanks for the reply

Comment: `^..5` would do the trick?

Comment: If you don't have the option to write code then why is this tagged as c#?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
^..5
```

- `^` - at start of line.
- `..` - match any two characters
- `5` - match 5

So RE will match only if third character is `5`.

```
var re = new Regex("^..5");
re.IsMatch("345678");   // True
re.IsMatch("qwerty");   // False
```